# Checking radiobutton to make make some selection

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, radio-button, checkboxlist

I want to make some selection via clicking radiobuttons. And I need that selection is active always. If I check another radiobutton the value in dropdown menu needs to change immediately.

> ai735 is id for my first radiobutton,
>
> ai736 is id for my second radiobutton,
>
> ai737 is id for my third radiobutton,
>
> ai764 is id for my dropdown menu.

This is what I tried;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('[name*="_ai735_"]').checked) {$('[name*="_ai764_"]').val("1").change();}
if ($('[name*="_ai736_"]').checked) {$('[name*="_ai764_"]').val("3").change();}
if ($('[name*="_ai737_"]').checked) {$('[name*="_ai764_"]').val("5").change();}
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal code sample here

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did it. Hope it is clear enough :/

Answer (score 0):

I managed it. Thanks for voting down my post instead helping.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

abc();

});


function abc(e)
{
$('[id*="_ai735_"]').change(function(){if ($(this).is(':checked')) {$('[name*="_ai764_"]').val("1").change();};});
$('[id*="_ai736_"]').change(function(){if ($(this).is(':checked')) {$('[name*="_ai764_"]').val("3").change();};});
$('[id*="_ai737_"]').change(function(){if ($(this).is(':checked')) {$('[name*="_ai764_"]').val("5").change();};});
}
```